# How do I align this div to the bottom-right/left in the parent div?

Tags: css, html

So, I have been trying to get the < div with id="action"> to the bottom of the < div with class="right">. In the code you can see I tried to do it with position relative and bottom :0 but it doesn't do anything. I can float to the right so that fine so I just need to get it to the bottom. Right now it just keeps placing right below the text.

```
echo "<div class=\"product\">";
    echo "<div class=\"left\">";
        echo "<div style=\"width:225px;height:180px;background:#ccc\">" . $obj->product_img_name . "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class=\"right\">";
        echo "<form method='post' action='update.php'>"; 
            echo "<h3>" . $obj->product_name . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>" . $obj->product_desc . "</p>";
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />';
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\" $obj->id \" />";
                    echo "<div id=\"action\" style=\"position:relative;bottom:0;float:right;\">";
                         echo $obj->price;
                         echo <input type=\"text\" name=\"quantity\" />";
                         echo "<input type='submit' value ='Add To Cart'>";
                    echo "</div>";
         echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
```

I thought it couldn't because of the div being in the form but I tried to put a div below the form and see if relative works but it still wouldnt work.

The css:

```
.wrapper{
    width:824px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#eeeeee;
}
.right{
    height:200px;
    width:550px;
    float:right;
}
.right p{
    font-size:0.95em;
}
.left{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
.product{
    height:200px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: if you're hoping for an answer, you might want to clean up your html...

Comment: Well guess what, just got the answer bud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.action` can be absolutely positioned...

```
.right {
  position: relative;
  /* other code */
}
.action {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* other code */
}
```